# Sybase 15 e Laravel 5.1 via ODBC e o erro 3811

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, odbc

Tenho um banco de dados em Sybase (Adaptive Server Enterprise) e começamos a usar o framework Laravel para transferir sistemas que já existem, para ele (uma migração no BD não pode ser cogitada).

O Laravel por padrão não consegue se conectar com o protocolo ODBC, muito menos com o Sybase. É possível, através do FreeTDS, usar o DBLib do SQLServer para essa tarefa, mas ela funciona apenas no Linux e eu preciso que isso seja possível tanto em Windows quanto em Linux.

Sabendo que o Laravel usa a função PDO, implementei, a partir dos códigos do SQLServer, classes para ser possível a conexão com o Sybase (a partir do protocolo ODBC e do driver Adaptive Server Enterprise).

Consigo fazer absolutamente tudo com o Sybase a partir do PDO com php puro, mas no Laravel, funciona apenas o SELECT, dando o mesmo erro pelo menos no UPDATE e no INSERT. Estou usando as mesmas configurações em ambos os casos, e ele dá os seguintes erros:

**Erro 1/2:**

```
PDOException in Connection.php line 358: SQLSTATE[ZZZZZ]: <<Unknown error>>: 3811 [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Um datastream incorreto foi enviado ao servidor. O servidor esperava o token 1 porém recebeu o token 0. Isto é um erro interno. (SQLExecute[3811] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)
```

**Erro 2/2**

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 621: SQLSTATE[ZZZZZ]: <<Unknown error>>: 3811 [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Um datastream incorreto foi enviado ao servidor. O servidor esperava o token 1 porém recebeu o token 0. Isto é um erro interno. (SQLExecute[3811] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254) (SQL: insert into [produtos] ([nome], [descr]) values (teste, teste))
```

O detalhe está que no Linux com o DBLib, funciona com as mesmas configurações para o Grammar e PostProcessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De certa forma consegui descobrir a natureza do erro mas não achei uma outra alternativa.

Basicamente o Sybase (ou o ODBC, mas chuto que não) não suporta esse tipo de inserção:

```
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela (campo) VALUES (?)")->execute(array("valor"));
```

Então, tenho que montar a query de maneira rústica, com explodes e loops e usar o comando `$pdo->query()`  para que funcione. O grande problema é que o Sybase não aceita inserção de todo tipo de dado entre apóstrofos e aí está o próximo grande desafio. :)

Comment: Provavelmente o Sysbase não aceita prepared statments.

Comment: Tem mais a ver com o ODBC no PDO, pois com o DBLib no Linux funciona sem nenhum engasgo, ou talvez seja mais um mistério sombrio sobre o Sybase.